# Unable to Increase the Interval of type Time In asp Chart Control diagram?

Tags: asp.net, charts, bar-chart

Can you help me,How to Increase interval in y-axis by one hour?, Thanks in advance.

```
 Chart2.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:00 tt";
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Chart2.Series[0].Points[i].AxisLabel = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString();
        }
```

View Image Click here  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/gj2sq4ewoxdvqpj/PROBLEM.jpg)